# Reading recommendation on using statistical analysis in online fraud prevention

Tags: books

Can you please recommend good reads on statistical analysis related to online fraud detection and prevention of account abuse?

Comment: i think this goes into the statsexchange forum, not here.

Comment: I think you should be more specific or this question may well be closed because it's off topic.

Comment: I'm not sure what fraud prevention has to do with Quantitative Finance.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, this isn't fraud, but it should be.   It's definitely account abuse.

http://articles.latimes.com/2011/apr/03/business/la-fi-amateur-currency-trading-20110403

http://ftalphaville.ft.com/blog/2009/11/02/80866/the-100bn-fx-hustle/

The sad part is, even after being shown this kind of information, I have watched several retail "traders" lose their ass on this crap.

Update (10/11/2013) =============================

No big surprise.

http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2013-10-11/u-s-said-to-open-criminal-probe-of-fx-market-rigging.html

Update (12/19/2013) =============================

Another "no big surprise".

http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2013-12-19/how-secret-currency-traders-club-devised-biggest-market-s-rates.html

Comment: good old bucketshops